# Ion Accordion: Can't cancel event propogation from icon clicked in the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework

I am trying to make it so an accordion list has a lockable button on the header; if the parent record is in a certain state, this shows the accordion as locked, however you should be able to click that lock icon as a button to *temporarily* unlock it.

However, whenever I click on this button, it also activates the accordion's default action (to toggle open/close of it).

Is there a way in which I can stop the event from propogating/bubbling to the accordion?

Here's a stripped down version of what I have so far:

```js
export const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {

    const onUnlock = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLIonIconElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        ev.stopPropagation(); // doesn't stop the accordion from opening/closing
        ev.preventDefault(); // also doesn't work
        ev.nativeEvent.cancelBubble = true // I was getting desperate; doesn't work
        // prevent the event propogation and update the state
    }
    return (
        <IonAccordion>
            <IonItem slot="header">
               <IonIcon icon={lockClosed} color="danger" onClick={onUnlock} />
            </IonItem>
        </IonAccordion>
    );
}
```